# Remove Configuration Management Destination

Tags: 8, drush, configuration

I'm using `drush cex` or `drush cim` to export and import configuration on D8 site.

Every time I run those commands, I get asked a question to select option for cancel, sync or staging, which is quiet annoying.

Is there a way to remove staging destination and only use sync so that I can use `drush cex -y` or `drush cim -y` without errors?

Answer (score 1):

Check please the arguments: https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/config/config-export. You can use directly `sync` in your command

```
   drush cex sync -y
```

Comment: thanks for quick response. I know that I can use `drush cex sync -y`. However, I just want to use drush cex -y without sync

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **$config_directories** in your settings.php and remove staging there

Besides, you can use Configs Split ( when you have different configurations for your available environments ) and set active one in settings.php

Comment: `$config_directories = ['sync' => '../config/default',];` this is what I have in settings.php for config directories.